# How to stop bootstrap resizing top card image too large whilst keeping consistent with differing image files?

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Hi I am having some trouble with bootstrap image sizing.

If I pass in a images with smaller dimensions it is "blowing them up" to fit the card and they can become blurry.

Here is the html in question:

{% for item in book_list %}
            
                
                    
                    
                        The Arsonist
                        Lorem Ipsum...
                        More Info
                    
                
            
        {% endfor %}
    

~~~

Now what is happening is when I render this I end up with this:

[image: render]

And whilst it might be difficult to tell from the screenshots the `card-img-top` are much larger than the source image this is not what I want for two reasons:

1. I would like the cards to be smaller, making them smaller and adding some white space either side would work fine.
2. It is resizing the images too large and this can make the images look blurry, especially when the resolutions are small to begin with and then they are blown up.

Can anyone tell me how I can make the cards images smaller whilst still staying the same size as the other cards images (which will have similar but not identical resolutions)?

I am looking for something like this (image on top is what I currently have and the black box is my fullscreen). It doesn't have to be 5 cards in a row or the margins don't need to be that big it is to just give an idea of what I roughly want.

[image: output]

It shouldn't matter what the dimensions of the original image is it should display like that, so for example if I put in a `2000x3000` image it shouldn't take up more space on the screen than a `200x300`.

**What I have tried so far:**

I have tried adding the custom CSS and playing around with the height

```
.card-img-top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 15vw;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

as well as trying the `style` attribute `style="width: 100%;"` which I figured might take the original image width as the width in the card and the height would follow, however in both cases it is still getting blown up. But nothing is working for me.

So to summarise my question again:

> How can I stop my card top images "blowing up" regardless of the dimensions of the image?

I am new to this kind of thing and new to this site so let me know please if I need to do more!

Thank you.

Comment: so your need is below image? inshort you need some whitespace in left and right side?

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that worked from me was changing class from "card-img-top" to "card-img"...

```
<img src="pic.jpg" class="card-img" style="width: 200px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row mb-5">
        <div class="col py-1 d-flex align-items-stretch">
            <div class="card m-3">
                <img src="https://www.booktopia.com.au/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/the-arsonist.jpg" class="card-img-top" style="width: 100%;" alt="image">

                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">The Arsonist</h5>

                    <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum...</p>

                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">More Info</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card  m-3">
                <img src="https://www.booktopia.com.au/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/the-arsonist.jpg" class="card-img-top" style="width: 100%;" alt="image">

                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">The Arsonist</h5>

                    <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum...</p>

                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">More Info</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card  m-3">
                <img src="https://www.booktopia.com.au/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/the-arsonist.jpg" class="card-img-top" style="width: 100%;" alt="image">

                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">The Arsonist</h5>

                    <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum...</p>

                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">More Info</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card m-3">
                <img src="https://www.booktopia.com.au/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/the-arsonist.jpg" class="card-img-top" style="width: 100%;" alt="image">

                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">The Arsonist</h5>

                    <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum...</p>

                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">More Info</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card m-3">
                <img src="https://www.booktopia.com.au/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/the-arsonist.jpg" class="card-img-top" style="width: 100%;" alt="image">

                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">The Arsonist</h5>

                    <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum...</p>

                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">More Info</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

see:https://jsfiddle.net/sugandhnikhil/rx4p8zgc/1/